# Issues with requests limit for Azure db

Tags: ssis, azure-sql-database

My setup is - SSMS connecting to Azure SQL server. This server has deployed on it a number of SSIS packages to be run.

When a package is under execution, I have the error shown below:

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error
> code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft
> SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description:
> "Resource ID : 1. The request limit for the database is 60 and has
> been reached. See 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=267637' for
> assistance."

.

After doing much research, I found that a potential solution was to decrease the MAXDOP amount. Set the value between 1 or 0. Doing this had no effect and did not prevent the error message.

Then, also as a result of research, I found out that I could restart the SQL services running. This ensured the SSIS package I execute could complete without errors twice! But on third attempt, the execution processes failed with the above error.

I found out online that there could be other reasons why I'm getting this error. Any chance someone can assist by pointing me in the right direction.

Many thanks
Thanks.

Comment: "Set the value between 1 and 0" so what did you set it to? What was the code you used? 0 won't fix your issue but 1 might.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I’ve set it to 0 (then ran the package, got the error) and then 1 (still same error). The code I used - ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET MAXDOP = 1. Ran this line of code against the db that I’m getting the error on. I initially used 0 as I thought that meant ‘unlimited’.

Comment: 0 means unlimited parallelism = lots of processes. 1 means only one.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid right, thanks. I only used 0 out of desperation. I still get the same error though, using 1 i.e.. I don’t know what else could cause the error. Something else is, I don’t know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a package with a data-flow task in it. This task was writing to over 30 table simultaneously.
In the end, I broke the task down into mini tasks, to reduce the number of simultaneous db access.

This solved my issue.